# Understanding a specific decorator, Why is there a function inside a function?

Tags: python, decorator

```
def lowercasewrapper(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return [item.lower() for item in func(*args, **kwargs)]
    return wrapper
```

I understand what decorators do, I have implemented the decorator above into my code and it works, but I'm little unsure about a few things.

1. Why can't (func) be replaced by (*args, **kwargs) and in the process remove the def wrapper line?  I'm guessing the first 2 lines don't do the same thing, but to me that's what it seems like.  It seems like:

   ```
   def lowercasewrapper(accept function) 
       def wrapper(accept function)
   ```
2. What is the significance of the word 'func' here?  I noticed I can replace that word with anything and my code still works.  Does the function I put below @lowercasewrapper just feed into the decorator regardless of whats in the '( )'?
3. Also, a little off topic but the word item also has no significance right?  I can replace that with any word as well and it still works.

I would appreciate if anyone would try to help and explain and answer in detail instead of redirecting me to a "what's a decorator" thread.

Comment: Maybe this [awesome post about python decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/1461780) would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is that a decorator actually turns this:

```
@decorated
def f(*args):
    # function body
```

Into this:

```
def f(*args):
    # function body
f = decorated(f)
```

So the reason you need the inner function is that the decorator *must return a function*, or the above makes no sense. With that in mind:

Point 1: notice that the last line returns `wrapper`, as in the function `wrapper` itself. This is why you can't remove that part; the function is actually building an altered function to return.

Points 2 and 3: You're right, it's just an arbitrary variable name and has no meaning outside this function.

So! With that in mind, here's what's going on in the decorator:

- `lowercasewrapper(f)` is called (where `f` is apparently assumed to return an iterable of strings)
- `lowercasewrapper` defines another function that takes some arbitrary arguments, then calls f on those arguments, then returns the result but with the items converted to lowercase
- `lowercasewrapper` then returns the altered function

The biggest obstacle here is likely to be the idea of *returning a function* as opposed to *returning the result of calling a function*. Read up on first-class functions (or see Leon Young's link) if this makes no sense to you.

Comment: Kind of makes more sense now. So the 4 lines are basically 1. Take in the decorated function. 2. take in the arguments from the decorated function and do whatever. 3. return the arguments 4. return the altered function?

Comment: Well, I'd alter that a little bit to say: 1: Take in the decorated function 2: Build an altered function that accepts the same arguments as the decorated function and does whatever 3: Return the altered function. Notice that when the altered `wrapper` function is called it just passes its arguments to `func` unaltered so it doesn't actually have to know or care what those arguments are.